# React JS: Element ref was specified as a string (inner) but no owner was set

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I would like to create a nice dynamic register html via React.js. However, I reached an error which I can't resolve..

This is the following error:

> Uncaught Error: Element ref was specified as a string (inner) but no owner was set. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
>   1. You may be adding a ref to a functional component
>   2. You may be adding a ref to a component that was not created inside a component's render method
>   3. You have multiple copies of React loaded

I used npm to install:

```
 $ npm install --save react react-dom
 $ npm install --save react-bootstrap
```

`register.js` **which is goes through webpacker and finally into bundle.js**

```
import { Grid, Row, Col, Panel } from 'react-bootstrap';

const SPECIAL_CHARS_REGEX = /[^A-Za-z0-9]/;
const DIGIT_REGEX = /[0-9]/;

class PasswordInput extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { password: '' };
    }

    render() {
        let { goodPasswordPrinciples } = this.props;


        return (
            <Grid>
                <Row>
                    <Col md={8}>
                        <PasswordField />
                    </Col>
                    <Col md={4}>
                        <StrengthMeter principles={goodPasswordPrinciples} />
                    </Col>
                </Row>
            </Grid>
        );

    }
}

PasswordInput.defaultProps = {
    goodPasswordPrinciples: [
        {
            label: "6+ characters",
            predicate: password => password.length >= 6
        },
        {
            label: "with at least one digit",
            predicate: password => password.match(DIGIT_REGEX) !== null
        },
        {
            label: "with at least one special character",
            predicate: password => password.match(SPECIAL_CHARS_REGEX) !== null
        }
    ]
};

class StrengthMeter extends React.Component {
    render() {
        let { principles } = this.props;

        return (
            <Panel>
                <h5>A good password is:</h5>
                <ul>
                    {principles.map(principle => 
                   <li>
                        <small>
                            {principle.label}
                        </small>
                   </li>
                    )}
                </ul>
            </Panel>
        ); 
    }
}

class PasswordField extends React.Component {
    render() { return null; }
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <PasswordInput />,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
```

My HTML file where I would like render my React code is:

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}

{% block body %}
<div id="root"></div>

<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<script src="{{url_for('static', filename='dist/bundle.js')}}" type="text/javascript"></script>

{% endblock %}
```

Finally,
I checked the 3rd suggestion of the error:

after running `npm ls react` i received this output `└── react@16.4.1` and nothing else.

Comment: What happens if you remove  both `<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>` 
? My intuition is that bundle.js already contains React but I am not sure.

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: React is not defined...

This doesn't seem as the solution..

Comment: And if you add `import React from 'react';`
in register.js? (just to be sure)

Comment: You just resolved my problem... Thank you very much...